# Flying-Saucer PDF Using :first With A Named Page

Tags: css, flying-saucer, css-paged-media

Currently in java I am generating an HTML document with applicable CSS styles.

I have verified that my document is correct, however it appears that the `:first` pseudo selector is not working when I use it in conjunction with a named page. as an example:

```
@page mainReport:first {
    @top-center {
        content: element(header);
        vertical-align: bottom;
    };

    @bottom-center {
        content: element(footer);
        vertical-align: top;
    };
}
```

The reason for me doing this is that I want to use the first page on a specific named page, does the CSS selector support this functionality for paged media? And if not, is there a work around for this issue, either through flying-saucer or some sort of CSS magic.

Thanks

Comment: I don't know Flying-Saucer _at all_ but maybe it's the same problem as in CSS: it may select the page that is 1/ named mainReport 2/ the first and not "the first mainReport found even if it is the 2nd+ page" (sth like "first-match", not even `:first-of-type`). Also in CSS it's `:first-child` and it exists in jQuery but I suppose it's also this syntax in Flying-Saucer

Comment: From what I understand from the CSS3 paged media specification, :first is an applicable pseudo selector when working with the @page selector. But I'll see if its not maybe just a CSS issue and let you know. Thanks

Comment: I stand [corrected](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-page/#first-pseudo) and will have learned something today, thanks ;)

Comment: I've tried playing around a bit using `:first-child` and a few others but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, [a named page is really a particular **type** of page](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-page-3/#using-named-pages), not a specific page. You can have multiple "special" **types** of pages, and use each type multiple times.

Secondly, all pages, regardless of their type, share the same page numbering and `page` counter. Therefore, there is really ever only a single page (namely, the very first one) in the document that matches the `:first` pseudo-class.

Therefore, if the first page of the document happens to be of the special type (e.g., `mainReport:first`) it will be styled accordingly. If the very first page is not of any special type, it will receive the default styling for a `:first` page (or `:right` page, in the absence of special styling for `:first`).

There is one thing that I noticed with Flying Saucer in this regard that caused me a little bit of a headache (and I find it somewhat counterintuitive). Whereas for regular pages (i.e., non-"named" ones), it is sufficient to specify `:left` and `:right` styles (assuming verso and recto pages are styled differently), I also had to define a `:first` style when additionally using a named page type.
For example, to have the table of contents numbered with Roman numerals I ended up with this:

```
@page :left
{
  margin-left: 0.6in;
  margin-right: 0.9in;
  @left-bottom {content: counter(page);}
}
@page :right
{
  margin-left: 0.9in;
  margin-right: 0.6in;
  @right-bottom {content: counter(page);}
}
@page toc:first
{
  margin-left: 0.9in;
  margin-right: 0.6in;
  @right-bottom {content: counter(page, lower-roman);}
}
@page toc:right
{
  margin-left: 0.9in;
  margin-right: 0.6in;
  @right-bottom {content: counter(page, lower-roman);}
}
@page toc:left
{
  margin-left: 0.6in;
  margin-right: 0.9in;
  @left-bottom {content: counter(page, lower-roman);}
}
```

If I leave out the `@page toc:first` section, Flying Saucer will apply the regular page numbers on the first page of the table of contents (but subsequent pages of the TOC will correctly have roman numeral page numbers).